# How to remove variable from graphQL query if it's empty?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, graphql

How do I omit the variable searchQuery if its value is an empty string, and have this logic inside of template literal?

Code:

```
var query = `query RunSearch($searchQuery: String, $mType: MediaType, $filterMethod:[MediaSort], $season:MediaSeason){
  Page(perPage:10, page: 1){
    pageInfo {
      total
      currentPage
      lastPage
      hasNextPage
      perPage
    }

    media(type: $mType, search: $searchQuery, sort:$filterMethod, season:$season){
    title{
    english
  }
    format,
    description(asHtml:true),
    averageScore,
    studios(isMain:true) {
      nodes {
        name
      }
    },
    coverImage {
      large
      color
    },
    genres
  }
  }

}`;
```

Comment: you can check the vars you get  and then build the query accordingly

Comment: You mean an if else statement with different query assignements? I've done that, but that's a lot of repeating code, is there no better way?

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/hbtqszfn/

Comment: Yea, needed to add another similar variable to this line tho, thanks
`media(${sq2} type: $mType, sort:$filterMethod, season:$season)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function using template string to build your query.
You can add more variables or controls to fit your needs.

```
const myvars = {
 searchQuery : "",
 mType : "pdf",
 filterMethod : "asc",
 season : ""
}


const buildQuery = (vars) => {
let sq = vars.searchQuery == "" ? "" : "$searchQuery: String,"
let mt = vars.mType == "" ? "" : "$mType: MediaType,"
let fm = vars.filterMethod == "" ? "" : "$filterMethod: [MediaSort],"
let ss =  vars.season == "" ? "" : "$season:MediaSeason"
var query = `query RunSearch(${sq} ${mt} ${fm} ${ss}){
  Page(perPage:10, page: 1){
    pageInfo {
      total
      currentPage
      lastPage
      hasNextPage
      perPage
    }

    media(type: $mType, search: $searchQuery, sort:$filterMethod, season:$season){
    title{
    english
  }
    format,
    description(asHtml:true),
    averageScore,
    studios(isMain:true) {
      nodes {
        name
      }
    },
    coverImage {
      large
      color
    },
    genres
  }
  }

}`;
return query;
}

let myquery = buildQuery(myvars);
console.log(myquery)
```